# Is that possible change default language of Apache's Index

Tags: apache, indexing

I have a page with Indexing enabled (and theme [Apaxy](http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/))

I've search a lot trying to figure out of how could I change default language (or simply change `STRING` values).

I have this:

[image]

Is that possible to change this text values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Foud a way using **jQuery** `.replace`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body table tbody tr th a').each(function(i){ // THE OBJECT WHERE IS THE REPLACEING TEXT
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Name','LOREN IPSUN'));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Last modified','LOREN IPSUN'));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Size','LOREN IPSUN'));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace('Description','LOREN IPSUN'));
   });
});
```

Just change *loren ipsun* for whatever you want.